# `list` of `list2env()` from `GlobalEnv`

Tags: r

I have the following list data: (I cannot upload more than one of the lists due to character limit, however I just created more lists replacing the name `GOOG.f` to `YHOO.f`, and `AMZN.f` etc.)

So I have many lists in the `GlobalEnv` called `YHOO.f`, `GOOG.f` and `AMZN.f` and then a vector

```
symbols <- c("YHOO.f", "GOOG.f", "AMZN.f")
```

I am trying to put all the `tickers` from the global environment into a `new.env()` only if they match the vector `symbols` - That is I am not trying to put everything into a `new.env()` just certain parts of the data.

```
tickers <- new.env()
```

When I run;

```
tickers <- list2env(GOOG.f)
```

Theres no problem in putting the google data into an environment but using;

```
ticks <- list2env(symbols)
```

Gives the following;

```
Error in list2env(symbols) : first argument must be a named list
```

Should I first try to put all the symbols into a list, so I will have a list of lists and then try `list2env()`?

List 1:

```
GOOG.f <- structure(list(IS = structure(list(`12/31/2017` = c(110855000, 
                                                         45583000, 65272000, 16625000, 19765000, NA, NA, 81973000, 28882000, 
                                                         -1689000, 28882000, -109000, 27193000, 14531000, NA, 12662000, 
                                                         NA, NA, NA, NA, 12662000, NA, 12662000), `12/31/2016` = c(90272000, 
                                                                                                                   35138000, 55134000, 13948000, 17470000, NA, NA, 66556000, 23716000, 
                                                                                                                   434000, 23716000, -124000, 24150000, 4672000, NA, 19478000, NA, 
                                                                                                                   NA, NA, NA, 19478000, NA, 19478000), `12/31/2015` = c(74989000, 
                                                                                                                                                                         28164000, 46825000, 12282000, 15183000, NA, NA, 55629000, 19360000, 
                                                                                                                                                                         291000, 19360000, -104000, 19651000, 3303000, NA, 16348000, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                         NA, NA, NA, 16348000, NA, 16348000), `12/31/2014` = c(66001000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               25313000, 40688000, 9832000, 13982000, NA, NA, 49127000, 16874000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               385000, 16874000, -101000, 17259000, 3639000, NA, 13620000, 516000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, 14136000, NA, 14136000)), .Names = c("12/31/2017", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "12/31/2016", "12/31/2015", "12/31/2014"), row.names = c("Total Revenue", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Cost of Revenue", "Gross Profit", "Research Development", "Selling General and Administrative", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Non Recurring", "Others", "Total Operating Expenses", "Operating Income or Loss", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Total Other Income/Expenses Net", "Earnings Before Interest and Taxes", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Interest Expense", "Income Before Tax", "Income Tax Expense", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Minority Interest", "Net Income From Continuing Ops", "Discontinued Operations", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Extraordinary Items", "Effect Of Accounting Changes", "Other Items", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Net Income", "Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments", "Net Income Applicable To Common Shares"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ), class = "data.frame"), BS = structure(list(`12/31/2017` = c(10715000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               91156000, 18705000, 749000, 2983000, 124308000, 7813000, 42383000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               16747000, 2692000, NA, 3352000, 680000, 197295000, 3137000, 3969000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               10651000, 24183000, 3943000, 16641000, NA, NA, NA, 44793000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, NA, NA, 40247000, 113247000, -992000, NA, -992000, 152502000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               133063000), `12/31/2016` = c(12918000, 73415000, 15632000, 268000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            3175000, 105408000, 5878000, 34234000, 16468000, 3307000, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2202000, 383000, 167497000, 2041000, 3935000, 5851000, 16756000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            3935000, 7770000, NA, NA, NA, 28461000, NA, NA, NA, 36307000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            105131000, -2402000, NA, -2402000, 139036000, 119261000), `12/31/2015` = c(15409000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       56517000, 13459000, 491000, 1590000, 90114000, 5183000, 29016000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       15869000, 3847000, NA, 3432000, 251000, 147461000, 1931000, 7648000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       4327000, 19310000, 1995000, 5825000, NA, NA, NA, 27130000, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       NA, NA, 32982000, 89223000, -1874000, NA, -1874000, 120331000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       100615000), `12/31/2014` = c(16585000, 46048000, 9974000, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2637000, 78656000, 3079000, 23883000, 15599000, 4607000, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    3363000, 176000, 129187000, 1715000, 8015000, 2803000, 16779000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2992000, 5320000, NA, NA, NA, 25327000, NA, NA, NA, 28767000, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    75066000, 27000, NA, 27000, 103860000, 83654000)), .Names = c("12/31/2017", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "12/31/2016", "12/31/2015", "12/31/2014"), row.names = c("Cash And Cash Equivalents", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Short Term Investments", "Net Receivables", "Inventory", "Other Current Assets", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Total Current Assets", "Long Term Investments", "Property Plant and Equipment", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Goodwill", "Intangible Assets", "Accumulated Amortization", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Other Assets", "Deferred Long Term Asset Charges", "Total Assets", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Accounts Payable", "Short/Current Long Term Debt", "Other Current Liabilities", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Total Current Liabilities", "Long Term Debt", "Other Liabilities", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Deferred Long Term Liability Charges", "Minority Interest", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Negative Goodwill", "Total Liabilities", "Misc. Stocks Options Warrants", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Redeemable Preferred Stock", "Preferred Stock", "Common Stock", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Retained Earnings", "Treasury Stock", "Capital Surplus", "Other Stockholder Equity", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Total Stockholder Equity", "Net Tangible Assets"), class = "data.frame"), 
                    CF = structure(list(`12/31/2017` = c(12662000, 6899000, 8284000, 
                                                         -3768000, 1121000, NA, 3682000, 37091000, -13184000, -19448000, 
                                                         1419000, -31401000, NA, NA, -86000, -3366000, -8298000, 405000, 
                                                         -2203000), `12/31/2016` = c(19478000, 6100000, 7158000, -2578000, 
                                                                                     333000, NA, 2420000, 36036000, -10212000, -18229000, -1978000, 
                                                                                     -31165000, NA, NA, -1335000, -3304000, -8332000, -170000, 
                                                                                     -3631000), `12/31/2015` = c(16348000, 5024000, 5609000, -2094000, 
                                                                                                                 246000, NA, 1618000, 26572000, -9950000, -13635000, 75000, 
                                                                                                                 -23711000, NA, NA, -23000, -2422000, -4225000, -434000, -1798000
                                                                                     ), `12/31/2014` = c(14136000, 4601000, 3615000, -1641000, 
                                                                                                         261000, NA, 1461000, 23024000, -11014000, -6222000, 628000, 
                                                                                                         -21055000, NA, NA, -18000, -2069000, -2087000, -433000, -551000
                                                                                     )), .Names = c("12/31/2017", "12/31/2016", "12/31/2015", 
                                                                                                    "12/31/2014"), row.names = c("Net Income", "Depreciation", 
                                                                                                                                 "Adjustments To Net Income", "Changes In Accounts Receivables", 
                                                                                                                                 "Changes In Liabilities", "Changes In Inventories", "Changes In Other Operating Activities", 
                                                                                                                                 "Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities", "Capital Expenditures", 
                                                                                                                                 "Investments", "Other Cash flows from Investing Activities", 
                                                                                                                                 "Total Cash Flows From Investing Activities", "Dividends Paid", 
                                                                                                                                 "Sale Purchase of Stock", "Net Borrowings", "Other Cash Flows from Financing Activities", 
                                                                                                                                 "Total Cash Flows From Financing Activities", "Effect Of Exchange Rate Changes", 
                                                                                                                                 "Change In Cash and Cash Equivalents"), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("IS", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            "BS", "CF"))
```

Comment: how about.. ` list2env(mget(symbols))`

Comment: That got what I wanted, thanks! I have now just the small point of trying to extract all the `BS`, `IS` and `CF` into a single `data.frame` for each `symbol`.

Comment: Done! `BS <- lapply(tickers, "[[", "BS")
CF <- lapply(tickers, "[[", "CF")
IS <- lapply(tickers, "[[", "IS")` Thanks again!

Comment: You can answer your own question if you consider you've got all figured out, this will e helpful for the next readers and the question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) suggested, apply `tickers <- list2env(mget(symbols))` and then it is possible to store the data using;

```
BS <- lapply(tickers, "[[", "BS")
CF <- lapply(tickers, "[[", "CF")
IS <- lapply(tickers, "[[", "IS")
```

which comes (to me) in a nicer more readable way. I just applied `t(BS)...` to carry out some financial calculations.